# Estoy utilizando la librería de Scapy.all y no puedo ejecutarlo

Tags: python

El error que me aparece al momento de ejecutarlo es el siguiente:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Unifranz\Trabajos TI\Wifi-Heatmap-main (1)\Wifi-Heatmap-main\main.py", line 4, in 
import scapy.all as scapy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.all'; 'scapy' is not a package

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Hola Andres, ¿por casualidad no tendrás algún modulo de Python u  otro archivo en ese directorio que se llame `scapy` o `scapy.py`?

Comment: La coletilla del error `'scapy' is not a package` no aparecería si simplemente no tuvieras instalado el paquete en ese entorno, eso indica que `scapy` existe pero o bien no es un paquete o no exporta nada, la causa más común de esto es un conflicto de nombres, tener un archivo llamado `scapy`/`scapy.py` en el CDW, el cual tiene preferencia sobre `sys.path` al importar. Si es así, renombra ese archivo y no uses nombres que entren en conflicto con la stdlib o paquetes de terceros instalados.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que instalar el paquete de `scapy`, para ello debes utilizar `pip` o `pip3` dependiendo la versión de Python que tengas instalado

```
pip install scapy
```

o

```
pip3 install scapy
```

Si el computador no reconoce el comando `pip` o `pip3` deberas instalarlo.

Dejo una [guía](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/install-pip-windows/) que podría  servir para instalar pip en windows.